# Assign numpy array to a pre initialized variable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to make this piece of code work.

```
mean = []

def func():
    mean = np.mean(a,axis=0);
print mean
```

But on printing `mean` I get an output `[]`. How can I assign `np.mean` to `mean`? 
PS: I am a beginner in numpy so I am quite confused on how variable assignment works here.

Comment: don't give your vars the same name as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mean` inside `func` isn't the same as the `mean` outside. When you assign `mean = ...` inside `func`, you are creating a *new* variable in `func`'s *local scope* - this `mean` is completely different from the `mean` defined outside, in *global scope*. Furthermore, the local variable with the same name hides the global variable, so in the end, the global variable is not touched.

The basic fix would be to declare `mean` as a `global` variable inside `func` and use the `out` param:

```
mean = np.empty(...)

def func(a):
    global mean
    np.mean(a, axis=0, out=mean) # you don't need the trailing semicolon either
```

However, for the sake of maintainable code I'd recommend *not* working with `global` variables at all when you can avoid it. Instead pass `a` as a parameter to `func` and return the result:

```
def func(a):
    return np.mean(a,axis=0)

mean = func(a)
```

The only event I'd recommend the former method is when it would make more sense performance wise. However, for a simple thing like computing the mean, why even declare a function in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You should `return` from your function

```
def func():
    return np.mean(a,axis=0);
```

Then you can assign the return value

```
mean = func()
```

Comment: This means `func` is operating on `a` assuming it is global; which I don't recommend.

Comment: Either that or `a` is (hopefully) a variable local within the function `func` and is some intermediate value